# Verify rdiff backup integrity

Tags: rdiff-backup, data-integrity, verification

I am using rdiff for my differential backup. Recently an issue happened where all versions of my backup failed to patch correctly and rdiff returning an error 106 which after investigation is a code for a corrupt delta.

Now I am pretty sure that the issue might be the result of a corrupt signature file since all deltas failed to patch correctly.

So my question is how do I verify if the signature file is corrupt or not or in other words how do I verify backups done using rdiff?